# Testing Material Design Angular components with jasmine

Tags: javascript, angular, testing, material-design, angular-material2

**Edit2**: Even more specific, using something like Material Button works fine. The Side Nav does not work well with the setup below, however.

**Edit**: I did more testing and found this is specifically related to Angular Material, as these errors don't occur without it. I'm still unsure how to fix it.

I'm trying to set up some basic tests for a new component, but I keep running into error after error. Specifically, after adding @angular/material to the project. The current error is:

```
Error: Found the synthetic listener @transform.start. Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your application.
```

Which feels like a red herring to me.

Here is the spec:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';

import { AngularNavigationComponent } from './angular-navigation.component';

describe('AngularNavigationComponent', () => {
    let component: AngularNavigationComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AngularNavigationComponent>;

    beforeEach(
        async(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                declarations: [AngularNavigationComponent],
                imports: [RouterTestingModule, MatSidenavModule]
            }).compileComponents();
        })
    );

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AngularNavigationComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

And here is the component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { RouterLink } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'mysupercustomcat-navigation',
    templateUrl: './angular-navigation.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./angular-navigation.component.scss']
})
export class AngularNavigationComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, and also perhaps explain declarations vs. imports in the Testbed configuration area?

Edit: This is a hybrid app if that matters

Comment: *feels like a red herring to me*?? WT? Material requires either `BrowserAnimationsModule` or `NoopAnimationsModule`. Add one to the application and be happy.

Comment: I've tried this already, it then throws an error in the @angular/material library, which is why I believe it's a red herring.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
at MatSidenav.ngAfterContentInit......node_modules/@angular/material/esm2015/sidenav.js:327:1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added two key sections to avoid errors like this:

```
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
```

is added at the top of the page and:

```
schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
```

is added at the same level as declarations.

What does this do? This tells angular not to error on unknown elements or attributes. Now this works **FOR THIS USE CASE** because I am not super interested in integration testing. I believe that might cause problems in this case.

I am interested in unit testing, and ignoring template attributes is fine with me. Adding this lets me get to that level.

This answer is as complete as I could get it for the moment.